# Assign date to all lines below until the next date

Tags: python, dataframe, data-manipulation

df

```
index      col1
------------------------
0          2017-01-01
1          a
2          b
3          c
4          2017-01-02
5          d
6          e
7          f
8          2017-01-03
9          g
10         h
11         i
```

expected df

```
index      col1              col2
------------------------------------------
0          2017-01-01        a
1          2017-01-01        b
2          2017-01-01        c
3          2017-01-02        d
4          2017-01-02        e
5          2017-01-02        f
6          2017-01-03        g
7          2017-01-03        h
8          2017-01-03        i
```

I want to assign dates to all the value below it and put them on the same line under two different columns (col1 and col2) from col1.

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines:

```
keep_rows = df['col1'].str.len() == 1 # These rows do not have dates
df['col2'] = np.nan
df.loc[~keep_rows, 'col2'] = df.loc[~keep_rows, 'col1']
df['col2'] = df['col2'].ffill()
df = df.loc[keep_rows]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using forward fill (`ffill`) method in `fillna` for  pandas dataframe/ series, after creating a *datetime* `col2`.

```
# extract datetime from col1
dates = pd.to_datetime(df['col1'], errors = "coerce")

# create a datetime column: col2 and forward fill
df['col2'] = dates.fillna(method = 'ffill')

# retain the required rows, reindex and rename
indx_retain = dates.isnull()
df = df[indx_retain].reset_index(drop = True)
df.rename(columns = {'col1':'col_2', 'col2':'col_1'}, inplace=True)
```